# Angular - mat-select inside mat-table - Show selected drop down value

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular-material-table, mat-select

Requirement:
I want to get the selected value printed in browser console when I click on the Save icon on each row. Here is my example.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-isif36-uokotq?file=app/select-value-binding-example.html

Problem 1:
When I write `[(ngModel)]="selectedDesc"` , the dropdown does NOT display the pre-selected values

Problem 2:
When I `[(ngModel)]="selectedDesc"` , and change the value on one row, it changes values in ALL rows.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: @Vega - Removed images

Comment: It could be great to add [mre]

Comment: I told [mre] not the whole project! The whole project is definitely not minimal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `value="{{element.acc_desc}}"` seems not to be required, because you use `ngModel`. Secondly, you need to bind to a property of the `element` in order to be able to select different account descriptions for each row. I am assuming you want to bind to `element.acc_desc`, so it should be `[(ngModel)]="element.acc_desc"` instead of `selectedDesc`.